# SSL авторизация backend к backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

Встала задача создать авторизацию между двумя приложениями которые будут написаны на `Ruby on Rails`.

**Идея:**
Есть сайт, назовем его `site1`, и есть второй сайт, пусть будет `site2`. Нужно что бы `site2` отправил определенную информацию для `site1` предварительно авторизовавшись на нем.

***ВАЖНО*** речь не идет о клиентской части в веб браузере, речь идет только о самом приложении на сервере.
Оба сервера находятся на разных машинах физически, которые не имеют доступ друг к другу по локальной сети.

Самое простое, это по логину и паролю да, но, человек имеющий доступ к серверу `site2` теоретически получит доступ к паре логин пароль, что нас не устраивает. По этому вопрос, возможно ли выполнить авторизацию на `site1` при помощи какого либо сертификата который можно было бы выдать только определенной машине в данном случае машине `site2` для авторизации на `site1` и как это будет происходить?

Comment: вообще да (tls auth), но на самом деле вам нужен oauth2.0

Comment: oauth2.0 на `site1` будет, потом что там будет авторизация через соцсети, но вопрос в том как сделать авторизацию для `site2` уникальной, что бы не кто другой не смог авторизоваться кроме `site2`

Comment: прочитать еще раз спецификацию oauth2.0, запрашивать авторизацию по client credentials и с определенными скоупами